# Telerik equivalent for DetailView

Tags: asp.net, telerik, detailsview

Is there a telerik equivalent for asp.net DetailView. Or can i customize a detailview to include telerik controls for editing (with minimum effort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's always RadGrid.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/gridoverview.html

I have bad experiences when combining standard, or other third party controls, with Telerik. They quite often act wierd, or don't work inside other controls.

Comment: I will just be editing one, unique record in form view. Isnt the grid supposed to be a list view for multipel records

Comment: Yes, and no. Both can be used for multiple rows. If I remember correctly, the GridView can read and edit db data records, while DetailsView can also create records. Don't quote me on that though. But a grid can be used for just one record with any problem.